# MySQL Server has Gone Away in Drupal 7

Tags: mysql, drupal

In my form field type, i edit the file menu these error will appear,

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in
>   D:\wamp\www\cms_development\includes\database\database.inc on line
>   2168 ( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL
>   server has gone away in
>   D:\wamp\www\cms_development\includes\database\database.inc on line
>   2168

Anybody Know how to rectify this error...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This may be because of max_allowed_packet

Change in the `my.ini/my.cnf` file. Include the single line under [mysqld] in your file

```
max_allowed_packet=500M
```

now restart the MySQL service once you are done. You can see it's curent value in mysql like this:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'
```

You can read about it here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html

Comment: If you have Super privileges with MySQL, you can run this query: **SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 1024 * 1024 * 500;**

Answer (score 0):

This is for Linux Users.In terminal,
Step 1:

`locate my.cnf`

*And you copy the Path*

Step 2:

```
sudo gedit "Paste the path"
```

Step 4:
Changed "**max_allowed_packet**" from "1m" to "32m" and saved ***my.cnf***

```
 sudo "path" restart
```

(or) **Do Normal System Restart**

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. mysql would crash while drupal8 was going through install process. restarting mysql would eliminate the "mysql has gone away ..." error but drupal install would never finish. the following combination of mysql and apache configs provided a stable digitalocean droplet for me:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mysql-server-keeps-stopping-unexpectedly?answer=26016