# How can I deal with failures when connecting to a MySQL cluster?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, high-availability

Our company has created two MySQL servers that are kept in synch using a master-master strategy. The two-machine cluster is managed using [crmsh](http://www.nongnu.org/crmsh/). This is only a high-availability cluster, meaning that one MySQL server is being sent data at a time, and the other is only kept for backup if one server fails.

To test our cluster (I haven't done this sort of thing before), I wrote a script that will write 100000 rows into a table in a database. While this script is running, I log in to the server that is receiving the data (I.E. the server that the shared IP is pointing to) and reboot it, trying to simulate a hardware failure.

In some cases, the script keeps running. In some other cases, however, I receive the infamous `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away` exception, or the `PDOException: SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction` exception, and so on.

How can I deal with these errors? I feel like there's a simple fact about programming for a cluster of servers that I'm unaware of.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981618/mysql-server-has-gone-away-in-drupal-7

Comment: I'm sending very small insert queries one at a time, not `source`ing a large file.

Comment: Have you considered posting this at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) instead? It's not off-topic here, but you might get a better response there.