# How can I solve missing bundle property

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-commerce

I am a drupal developer learner.When I open the order page from admin/commerce/orders then its display error look like:
Missing bundle property on entity of type commerce_order.
**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 154573161 bytes) in** /var/www/vhosts/shop.kayaclinic.com/httpdocs/includes/database/database.inc on line 2168

So how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

To answer correctly need some clarification of details.
version of modules used, context(for example how many orders do you have etc)

See [MySQL Server has Gone Away in Drupal 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981618/mysql-server-has-gone-away-in-drupal-7) it may solve Your case.

1. Restart server(mysql, apache), than if not helped increase memory limit to check what is going on, but with great probability there is problem in code if this step did not help.
2. Check watchdog or syslog
   for other errors before current behavior happened. You need to check
   which action caused this behavior.
3. If You do not use memcache(d), maybe you should try it.

Regards